# Why is my image not filling the box in my grid

Tags: css

I'm trying to completely fill the grey boxes with my picture I'm uploading. But it wont completely fill the box and leaves a big grey border around the photo. How do I make it fill the box while keeping everything even and in line.

```
.grid-wrapper{
    display:grid;
    grid-gap:20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(350px,1fr));
}

.box>img{
    width:100%;
}
.box{
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 130px;
    margin:20px;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.box:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Please show a snippet which has the relevant HTML in it also and make it so we can run it to see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have a lot of padding in each box.